# Dynamically declare a class constructor while still using generic parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm running into an error with trying to dynamically declare a class constructor. See the following:

```
export default function createBatches<type = object>(
  batchClass: { new (recipe: batchRecipe<type>): Batch<type> } = Batch
): Batch<type>[]
```

```
new batchClass<type>()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ERROR: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.
```

vs

```
new Batch<type>()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        OKAY
```

Does anybody know how can I dynamically declare a class constructor while still using generic parameters?

PS: I've also tried this, which yields an error:

```
export default function createBatches<type = object>(
  batchClass: { new (recipe: batchRecipe<type>): Batch<type> } = Batch<type>
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                 ERROR: "A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation."
): Batch<type>[]
```

Comment: Can you be explicit about 1) what params do you want the function to accept (if any) and 2) what do you want it to return?

Comment: I'm hoping for it to accept a Class that's a sub-type of `Batch` (or just use `Batch` if none others are provided) and then return the instance of Class `Batch` that's created.


There are also some misc parameters for the Class that I've removed for clarity's sake.

The `type` parameter declares the type of object that exists within the batches.

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. The code you posted in your first snippet [just works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBGYBdgAsBKBTYBLADugPACoB80A3gL4BQokMAQoikaZVVegB44D2ATgmgATdADMwAVxCDREgHbAEWHnOjA+6ROkZJk6CPgQBPPNAC80HrABWmBMQAUVaHCbIAwuCgAuctDnoAO7QDhrYeL7wuhjhBMZ4xACUvjrM8eikFObQqchUyTluhiYZANoAuuTO0BoIEnyqFVQUQA).

Comment: It's the second code-block, when I try to instantiate a `batchClass` but with a specific `<type>` parameter, I end up getting an error.

Comment: @user1543574 The `batchClass` argument of your function is not generic, only your complete `createBatches` function is. You just call `new batchClass()` and will automatically get a `Batch<type>` for the `type` that was chosen for that specific `createBatches<…>(…)` call.

Comment: I see, but how does Typescript make the inference that `type` of `batchClass` should be the same as `createBatches`?

Comment: @user1543574 Because you said in the declaration that `batchClass` has the type `{ new (recipe: batchRecipe<type>): Batch<type> }`, where the type variable `type` is bound by the type parameter of `createBatches<type = object>`.